# Firebase query returns different results every time

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this request to a firebase database. I would expect it to return all the records in the quotes collection. However, it returns a different set of records (including a different total row count) every time. What do I need to do to “export” all records in a collection consistently?

```
db.collection("quotes").get()
.then(snapshot => {
  console.log(snapshot);

  let snapshotArray = [];
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    const data = doc.data();
    snapshotArray.push(data);
  });


  return res.status(200).send(snapshotArray.length)


})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
  res.status(500).send(error);
});
```

Comment: Are there two documents in your collection with those ids? I'm not sure the question makes sense you should be expecting to receive all documents in your quotes collection with the query above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna get data of one document you gotta know what its name is. You should check if it does exist as well:

```
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
if (doc.exists) {
    console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
} else {
    // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
    console.log("No such document!");
}
}).catch(function(error) {
console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

If you want a saved field like ID, you gotta write it this way:

```
console.log("Document data:", doc.data().id); // only saved ID gets printed
```

Comment: Hello Peter thank you for your answer.
The problem is that I don't have to get just one doc but all the collections "quotes" to create a CSV of the collections.
Everything run fine but the CSV every time have different numbers of records.
Do you have any idea why?

Thank You!

Comment: Hey @Andrea Vitale, maybe you can find this here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection